# Database structure - associations in a multiuser system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the process of building a multiclient system in ROR. (I am looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

The structure is that a client has a contract, so when he logs in with his username, password and contract, he will have access to the system.

We have the contract id as a “master key”, which has to be in every table in the system.

```
class CreateContracts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contracts do |t|
      t.integer  :contract_id
    end
  end
end
```

(chart of accounts)

```
class CreateCoas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :coas do |t|
      t.integer  :account_id
      t.string    :account_name
    end
  end
end


class CreateCustGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :custgroups do |t|
      t.integer  :account_id1
      t.integer  :account_id2
      t.integer  :account_id3
    end
  end
end
```

Q1: How do I define the contract with belongs_to? There has to be a relation in every table in the system to the contract table. Do I have to have a relation to all tables? (I think so)

```
class Contracts < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :Coas
  has_many:xxx
  belongs:to
end
```

Q2: How do I define the association on the custgroup? Here we have a record where I have 3 or more fields that link to the same table (COA).

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the relations between the different models in more detail. Right now, it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Jesper -made a typing error  -see below

Answer (score 1):

As Jesper said, it's quite hard to follow what you're trying to achieve, but I'll try to reply  to your questions :

Q1 : If you want all your tables to reference a contract, you'll need to add to all those tables a foreign_key such as `contract_id`
so each create_table call will have the contract_id key

```
create_table :new_models do |t|
  t.belongs_to  :contract # this will create a contract_id field
end
```

you can also add an index on the column

```
add_index :new_models, :contract_id
```

then in all you models you'll add the `belongs_to` association :

```
class NewModel
  ...
  belongs_to :contract
  ...
end
```

so if your `Coas` & `CustGroups` needs to reference the contract table, you'll have to change both migrations to include the `contract_id` key and then the models to add the `belongs_to` association

If a `contract` needs to have access to all `Coas` that references it, then you need to use the `has_many` association

```
class Contracts < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :coas
  ...
end
```

It doesn't look like you need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` here, but i might be wrong about that.
if a contract also needs to access to CustGroups, you'll add :

`has_many :cust_groups` in the `Contract` model.

Q2 : I really didn't get understand what you want to do. Please explain what is the relation between Coas and Custgroups and I'll try to help you

Comment: Hi pjam
Sorry I made a typing error
Should has been 
   class custgroups < ActiveRecord::Base not

   class Contracts < ActiveRecord::Base
  

I have a customer group where I has to link to different accounts in my char of accounts

I need 3 accounts per record in my customer group

Comment: Mmmm, I didn't really get what you said, so did my answer helped you or do you need more explanations ?